# How to apply noise to volume mesh in geometry nodes to arbitrary shape?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

[image]

It turns out to transform the cube into a volume with noise. but the arbitrary form cannot be converted, it gives an error. How can I fix this?

Comment: The _Volume Cube_ accepts a field of values for the _Density_ input (diamond-shaped), the _Mesh to Volume_ does not, only a single value (circle-shaped).

Comment: you could turn the mesh into an sdf which you could use in a volume cube, or there might be a node that could work in the new volume nodes that you could enable under developer extras experimental